# How to find an equation of the plane through a line and parallel to the line of intersection of two other planes

Tags: linear-algebra, education

Find an equation for the plane that contains the line x=1+t,y=3t,z=2t and is parallel to the line of intersection of the planes −x+2y+z=0 and x+z+1=0

Here's the solution:

(−1,2,1)×(1,0,1)=(2,2,−2)

(2,2,-2)x(1,3,2)=(10,-6,4)

But my lecturer said the answer should be 5x-3y+2z-5=0 ?

Comment: What have you tried? I'm asking because it could be that your own work is just a step away from the correct answer.

Comment: First you find the direction vector of the second line as [$(-1,2,1)\times (1,0,1)=(2,2-2)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%2C2%2C1%29%5Ctimes+%281%2C0%2C1%29), then you cross product the lines' directional vectors to get the normal vector of the desired plane. Then you need a point on the plane, say $(1,0,0)$ and the result is $(x-1,y-0,z-0).n=0$ where [$n=(10, -6, 4)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%2C+2%2C+-2%29%5Ctimes+%281%2C3%2C2%29). Not worth to be an answer. Because the answer should explain why.

Comment: I've tried but I couldn't solve it, here my solution: –x+2y+z=0
x+z+1=0

x=-1-t
y=4-t
z=-t

{x=1+t, y=3t, z=2t}
(x=-1-t, y=4-t, z=-t}

Comment: Please do respond to comments by editing the question instead. This (adding your tries to solve the problem, into the question) may prevent the question from being closed. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, thankyou, wait I'll change it:)

Answer (score 1):

Compute the cross product of $(-1,2,1)$ and $(1,0,1)$ which are the normal vectors to the intersecting planes. With the result, take cross product with $(1,3,2)$, the direction of the given line, to get the normal vector to your desired plane. Then find a point on the plane to get the full equation.

Comment: Here we got (10,-6,4), but why the correct answer should be 5x-3y+2z-5=0? I don't get it. I'm sorry I'm not good enough in linear algebra.

Comment: Well, if the normal vector is $(10, -6,4)$ the equation is $10x - 6y + 4z= P$ where $P$ follows from finding a point on the line (say $(1,0,0)$, so $P=10$ follows). But then divide both sides by $2$ and you get your model answer. @sherlysantiadi

Comment: Okayy, I get it, thankyou very much, this answer really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

From the parametric equation of the line, you have instantly points on this  line, and a directing vector $u$.

On another hand, from the equations of the planes, you have normal vectors of each of these planes, $n_1$ and $n_2$. A directing vector of their intersection line is $n_1\wedge n_2$.

Therefore, a normal vector for the plane you seek for, is $\;u\wedge(n_1\wedge n_2)=(u\cdot n_2)n_1-(u\cdot n_1)n_2$ by the double vector product formula.

This should be enough to obtain the equation of the plane.